# Save selected value from list box to variable

Tags: variables, listbox, autoit

I have a list box of values and I want to save the selected value in a variable. I found a lot of things about list box and looked up many functions but didn´t find the way how to get the selected item.

```
$ListBox = _GUICtrlListBox_Create($GUI2, "1111111-xx1" , 0, 0) 

_GUICtrlListBox_AddString($ListBox, "1111111-xx1") 
_GUICtrlListBox_AddString($ListBox, "2222222-xx2")


GUISetState() ;show the gui
Local $idMsg = 0
 While 1
        $idMsg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select

      Case $idMsg = $btn_copy

;~  here
;~   i need take value from listbox and close gui
;~  after that i start batch file... but important - i need after button click set selected value to variable

                Exitloop   
      EndSelect
   WEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`GUICtrlRead`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlRead.htm) to retrieve the selected value of a combobox:

```
$comboVal = GUICtrlRead($ListBox)
ConsoleWrite("You selected: " & $comboVal & @CRLF)
```